# equivalent of `foo ./**/foo` (bash/zsh command with glob) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In macOS/Linux bash/zsh I can do this:

```
rm -rf ./**/foo
```

to remove all `foo` files/folders anywhere in the current folder, any level deep.

What's the equivalent with Windows PowerShell?

```
rm -r -fo <what goes here?>
```

Comment: Can you please try `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Include foo -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force`? I surmise this should do the task for you.

Comment: As an aside: For `**` to result in _recursive globbing_ in Bash, opt-in via `shopt -s globstar` is required (in Zsh it seems to be enabled by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows powershell we can use `Remove-Item` cmdlet to delete files or directories. And since you provided the `glob` in mac, to recursively delete all files named "foo" in the current directory and its subdirectories, you can use the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Include foo -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
```

**Explanation of above command:**

- **`Get-ChildItem -Path . -Include foo -Recurse`** - gets all items named "foo" in the current directory and its subdirectories.
- **`Remove-Item -Force`**  - deletes each item. The `-Force` param is used to delete read-only files as well. You can ignore it as per your need.

Comment: Nice, but note that in order to delete _nonempty directories_ without triggering an _interactive prompt_, you must use `-Recurse` also with `Remove-Item`. It is also helpful to _preview_ deletions using the [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif). `-Filter foo` will perform noticeably better than `-Include foo` (though the two aren't always interchangeable).

Comment: Dang, so there are no globa in pwsh, is basically it.

Comment: Looks like `-Path` is not needed. Is there something shorter than this? `Get-ChildItem -r -i node_modules | rm -r -fo`

Comment: @trusktr: `gci -r -i foo | ri -r`. Add `-fo` for `-Force` only if you want to override `ReadOnly` attributes on Windows. Add `-wi` for `-WhatIf`. Generally, however, note that abbreviating parameter names like that in PowerShell is an _interactive_ convenience, but shouldn't be relied on in _scripts_, as long-term stability cannot be guaranteed: should new parameters be introduced that make these abbreviated parameter names _ambiguous_, that code would break.

Comment: If you want to know which aliases are available for a given command, use `Get-Alias -Definition`; e.g., `Get-Alias -Definition Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Alias -Definition Remove-Item`. For conceptual clarity, it's best to avoid aliases named either for another platform's standard utility (e.g., `rm` on Unix) or another shell's internal command (e.g., `cmd.exe`'s `rmdir` on Windows). PowerShell has _platform-independent_ aliases that are formed from prescribed alias prefixes for the _approved verbs_ used in PowerShell cmdlet names, e.g. `r` for `Remove`, as used in `ri` for `Remove-Item`.

Comment: @trusktr, yes the command can be shortend by aliases. The major issue with shortening is they are easier to type and difficult to understand. That's why I shared the longer command.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for suggesting the shortened command and `-filter` flag usability.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks! "should new parameters be introduced ... that code would break". Any idea what are the chances of that happening?

Comment: @trusktr, it happens only rarely, especially not with long-established cmdlets, but it is a possibility. Another way to avoid the problem is to use explicit parameter _aliases_, such as `-s` for `-Recurse` and `-lp` for `-LiteralPath`, but such aliases aren't consistently defined; e.g., there are none for `-Include` or `-Force`